# Call Javascript function after another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

**I need to call a javascript function after this on keypress-based function is completed.**

*-function to auto-filter gridview records on textbox keypress*

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          function filter2(phrase, _id) {

              var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
              var table = document.getElementById(_id);

              var ele;

              for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
                  ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
                  var displayStyle = 'none';
                  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                      if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0) {
                          displayStyle = '';

                      }
                      else {
                          displayStyle = 'none';
                          break;
                      }

                  }  
                  table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;       
              }
          }
```

**the function to be called after**

*-function to fixate gridview header*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/JQueryUICalendar/js/gridviewScroll.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


        var $160 = jQuery.noConflict();
        $160(document).ready(function () {
            gridviewScroll();
        });

        function gridviewScroll() {
            $160('#<%=grdTenant.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
                width: 1080,
                height: 340,
                // freezesize: 2, //kung gusto mag free yung column enable this pls
                //IsInUpdatePanel: true
                arrowsize: 30,
                varrowtopimg: "images/arrowvt.png",
                varrowbottomimg: "images/arrowvb.png",
                harrowleftimg: "images/arrowhl.png",
                harrowrightimg: "images/arrowhr.png"
            });
        }

</script>
```

**This is what I did, I put gridviewScroll() at the end of the first function, but expected output does not work.**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
              function filter2(phrase, _id) {

                  var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
                  var table = document.getElementById(_id);

                  var ele;

                  for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
                      ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
                      var displayStyle = 'none';
                      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                          if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0) {
                              displayStyle = '';

                          }
                          else {
                              displayStyle = 'none';
                              break;
                          }

                      }  
                      table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;       
                  }
                  gridviewScroll();
              }
```

**Textbox that calls filter2() function**

```
   <input id="txtTerm" name="txtTerm" type="text" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdTenant.ClientID %>')"  size="40"  />
```

**expected output** should retain the format correctly (aligned gridview header to gridview items) while auto-filtering the gridview records. columns are mis-aligning on the currect scenario.

Comment: Put this in fiddle please

Comment: How is `filter2()` executed? What calls this?

Comment: Hi @twisty updated the question already. It is called by a textbox onkeyup event